# Webmin Cluster Copy Protocol

Tags: web-server, cluster, copying

Just toying with a clustered server farm for fun (as you do) and experimenting with Webmin and its 'clustered' modules.

It has a feature that can copy files from one server to another on a repeating basis. Does this feature/module use cron jobs and what protocol does it use to copy the files?

I have searched all about the net and yet I cannot find any decent documentation on webmin or its features. Is it just poorly documented or am I missing something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it is not a service providers interface. It is an open source server management application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently discovered that it uses it's OWN protocol using a specific port. A few above 10000 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that it uses rsync with cron, which is the canonical way of handling this type of replication. I would be very surprised if they used anything else.